# maven-release-plugin deploys snapshot to archiva

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

How can I force mvn release:perform to deploy to my release and not tom my snapshot repository? release:perform always deploys SNAPSHOT versions. Which makes no sense IMHO

I have in my pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
<artifactId>MyArtifactName</artifactId>
<version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>


<name>MyArtifactName</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo.example.com/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        <name>libs-release-local</name>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <name>libs-snapshot-local</name>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<scm>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>http://git.example.com/someUser/myproject</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git@git.example.com/someUser/myproject.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@git.example.com/someUser/myproject.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Is the distribution management of your pom.xml correct? http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repository

Comment: what is the artifact's name and version?

Comment: I edited the question above.

Comment: You are using the same `<id>` for your snapshot and release repositories. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Stefan Ferstl: No, this also didn't help. Even with different ID's running a ´mvn release:perform´ always deploys to the SNAPSHOT repo... annoying... somehow...

Comment: One more thing: When running "mvn deploy" the artifacts are deployed to the right repos (depending on having SNAPSHOT-QUalifier or not in the version). The problem only occurs with the mvn release plugin...

Comment: Are you using Git as version control system? When you configure the maven-release-plugin with the `suppressCommitBeforeTag` flag, you'll have exactly the effect you are describing.

It would be helpful if you could add more information about your POM file to your question, e.g. the configuration of the maven-release-plugin, scm settings, etc.

Comment: @StefanFerstl thanks, for your answer, I provided a little bit more information above. One thing I realized is, that the pom.xml in the tagged version created by "mvn release:prepare" still has the SNAPSHOT-qualifier.,,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem: The problem is, that I needed to update the `maven-scm-provider-gitexe` dependency, for the `maven-release-plugin` (version 2.4.2), when using Git as SCM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I found the solution here: [mvn release:prepare not committing changes to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166781/mvn-releaseprepare-not-committing-changes-to-pom-xml)

You can find a working example here: https://github.com/tarator/releaseplugintest

Comment: You're my hero today.