# Maven release - Snapshot

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin

I have problem in maven release

Whenever i try to release my application, always the snapshot version gets released. I am not able to release non-snapshot version, even though during the mvn release:prepare i give non-snapshot version the snapshot version gets released.

**maven 3.1.1**

**Example:**

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

version to be release : 0.1

But version 0.1-SNAPSHOT get released.

But non-snapshot version gets released in other machines.

Comment: Have you written the version `0.1-SNAPSHOT` or have you written it `0.1-snapshot`? Best is you show your pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise thats fine.. i missed the case sensitive in my question

Comment: Than please show your pom file and how you call maven and what happen and what you expect to happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mvn release:prepare not committing changes to pom.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166781/mvn-releaseprepare-not-committing-changes-to-pom-xml)

Comment: you need to `mvn release:perform` to release artifact to other machines!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512011/maven-release-plugin-deploys-snapshot-to-archiva?rq=1