# Why does mvn release:perform always create a new snapshot version and upload that to the repository instead of the non-snapshot release version?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

1. I have created a public repo in Bitbucket to hold all the releases and snapshot releases for me.
2. I am using wagon-git to upload the jar to the releases repository.

Here are my entries in pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>synergian-repo</id>
    <url>https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
...
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>my id</id>
    <name>my repo name</name>
        <url>my repo url</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
...
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>ar.com.synergian</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-git</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.5</version>
    </extension>
....
</build>
```

What I am doing:

1. `mvn clean package` (creates snapshot version)
2. `mvn release:prepare` (creates the new release version and uploads that jar and tags appropriately into my git repository)
3. I checkin the updated pom.xml, release.properties etc.
4. `mvn release:perform` - With this step I am expecting the new release version created by step 2 to be uploaded to my repository holding all the release jars.

Instead, mvn release:perform creates a new snapshot version and uploads that snapshot jar to the releases repository.

Question is: How do I manage to upload the non-snapshot release jar to the repository instead always creating and uploading a new snapshot version?

What am I missing?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166781/mvn-releaseprepare-not-committing-changes-to-pom-xml. The problem was that at the end of the release:prepare step, the pom.xml was not getting committed, and hence release:perform step was compiling and generating the snapshot version again. I am using maven-release-plugin 2.5.2 and maven-scm-provider-gitexe version 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem here: [mvn release:prepare not committing changes to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166781/)…. The problem was that at the end of the release:prepare step, the pom.xml was not getting committed, and hence release:perform step was compiling and generating the snapshot version again. I am using maven-release-plugin 2.5.2 and maven-scm-provider-gitexe version 1.9.2