# mvn release:prepare do not commit and do detect local changes

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have two strange behavior with my mvn release:prepare

1/ It do not stop when there is local changes not committed even if it detect them !

```
[DEBUG] release.properties not found - using empty properties
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\pom.xml.next, **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag, **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --show-toplevel"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\XX
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status --porcelain ."
[INFO] Working directory: D:\XX
[DEBUG] A  testFab2
[DEBUG] ?? release.properties
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "XX-parent"? (YY:XX-parent) 1.3.2: :
```

2/ It doesn't commit and push the modified pom.xml...

And more confusing, the normal behaviour occurs well on my colleague computer. We have the same configuration. Here some tech infos :

Git

```
git version 2.16.2
```

mvn --version

```
 Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T20:49:05+01:00)
 Maven home: D:\tools\apache-maven-3.5.3
 Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
 Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
 OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

plugin maven-release

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version>
   <configuration>
       <goals>install</goals>
       <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
       <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
       <preparationGoals>verify</preparationGoals>
       <arguments>-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dmaven.site.skip=true</arguments>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hve tried downgrade the pluginlike in this post : [mvn release:prepare not committing changes to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166781/mvn-releaseprepare-not-committing-changes-to-pom-xml), but without success

If you have some ideas...
Thank you

Comment: The log in part (1) says it is ignoring temporary files used by the release plugin, like `pom.xml.next`.  It does _not_ ignore changes to pom.xml.  Are you actually seeing a diff?  What is your SCM & repository config?  Share the whole POM for a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score -1):

Use maven command with PushChanges=false.

Comment: Could you explain the effect, write a sample and/or add a reference to documentation, please ?